# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor causes MemoryLeak in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, concurrency

I have a Spring 3 application that runs inside Tomcat 7.

I am using Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to process some messages off a queue. I have a bean that uses @Scheduled which submits tasks to the executor every 100 millis.

However, I have noticed when I shutdown Tomcat, it warns me that it can't shutdown some tasks.

```
SEVERE: The web application appears to have started a thread named [taskExecutor-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Nov 28, 2012 1:29:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
```

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Most likely, the thread was in the process of shutting down but didn't complete quickly enough. I think you can safely ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the shutdown method on the executor bean? I was able to get around this by doing this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
     public Executor taskExecutor() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
     }
```

Ref:

> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RC1_to_3.2.0.RC2/changes/docdiffs_org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.html

Comment: I know this a very old thread; nonetheless I do have the same issue implementing above strategy doesn't solve my issue... was there anything else that could resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true)` when you wire up the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

The documentation is here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean), and it says the default value is false.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However it looks like there is a bug in Spring 3 with this setting: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5387